# what do <form action=“.”>

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap, forms

I have a basic question. I cannot find an explanation of form action="." despite searching for  on google, www.w3schools.com, etc...

Anyone know what the . action means for forms? Is it specific to Django? Bootstrap?

Code below:

```
{% extends "Blog.html" %}
{% block blog%}
  <h1>Create an account</h1>
  <p>Please, sign up using the following form:</p>
  <form action="." method="post">
    {{ user_form.as_p }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Create my account"></p>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Form Action attribute specifies where to send the form-data when a
>   form is submitted

*Possible accepted values:*

1. **An absolute URL**: points to another web site (like action="http://www.example.com/example.htm")
2. **A relative URL** - points to a file within a web site (like action="example.htm")

in your case of `action="."` you are pointing to current url/file/directory. 
So it will reload the same page on form submission.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, the `action` attribute in a form specifies where the data should go to, for example a processing file: `action="proces.php"`.

Sometimes, `action="#"` or `action="."` is used to reload the page and process the data on the same page.

Basically, it just submits the form to the same page.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: whwn we use ```action="proces.php"``` ? in my opinion everyone writes action="Same Page"

Answer (score 1):

It reloads the current page, but with new data.